# Getting "(406) Not Acceptable" when trying to download a git repo using powershell

Tags: git, powershell

I am trying to download a repo as a zip file using powershell. Below is how I am trying to do it.

```
$token = "MyGitToken";
$repo = "https://github.com/my-private-repo/archive/master.zip";
$targetFile = "./master.zip";
$restRequest = @{
    Method  = "Get"
    Uri     = "$repo"
    Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Token $token"
        Accept        = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw"
    }
};

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @restRequest -OutFile $targetFile;
```

I am getting below error. Any idea how this can be fixed as suggested in the comments..

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (406) Not Acceptable.   
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
```

PS: I am able to download the zip file when I directly hit the $repo url in a browser.

EDIT: Updated the `Invoke-RestMethod` command to use just `OutFile` instead of piping it.

Comment: Try it without the `Accept` header. I can download a zip file from GitHub without it. Also, [`Invoke-RestMethod` has an `OutFile` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--run-a-post-request) if you were unaware.

Comment: @Ash: Not sure why you mentioned about OutFile parameter. I already have the `OutFile` parameter in my request. 

Thanks for the suggestion regarding Accept header. I removed it and I see the file getting downloaded...

Comment: I was referring to the fact that you are using the cmdlet [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7.1) and not the included parameter within [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--run-a-post-request). There is no need to pipe it to the next cmdlet. Glad you got your issue fixed anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP Accept header is an instruction to the server saying

> Hey, I can **ONLY UNDERSTAND these formats**

So, in your request you're saying

> Github, I want this file BUT I also want you to do some work for me and make it into this format, kthanxbai

GitHub is responding 406 Unacceptable because it don't have time for you or your weird request formats, and also because you left off the `*` option at the end, which means "I'll take this in any format".

To fix, try to do the request without an Accepts header, or modify your header like this:

```
  Accept        = "application/vnd.github.v3.raw,*"
```

Source:

> The Accept header tells the server what file formats, or more correctly MIME-types, the browser is looking for...

https://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers